# What should be the size/package of Bob Smith Termination resistor?

Tags: resistors, ethernet, packages, termination

We have run into a layout issue where the size/package of the 75R resistor used for Bob Smith termination on unused Ethernet pins is in question. The current package of this resistor is 1206 and we want to reduce it to 0603 size. Can this be done?

As far as I know or can think of, it can be done without any problems. But just want a confirmation. Some brief justification would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in reading http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161436

Comment: Although I am unfamiliar with Bob and his termination ;-) from a transmission line/cable termination point of view I would say: the cable obviously needs to be terminated with 75 ohms, this can be done with any 75 ohms resistor, 1206 or 0603. I would have a look at the required power dissipation of the resistor though. If there are signals on the line these must be dissipated in the resistor. Since an 0603 is smaller it can handle less power. If the DC component on the line is causing most dissipation, a series capacitor might solve that.

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie - the Bob Smith termination is for common mode signals on ethernet lines and not for direct termination. Direct terminations are still needed.

Comment: OK, now I see that indeed, didn't look at the schematic in the article in enough detail. But then dissipation caused by the signal should be even less of an issue (assuming the signals are differential and the common mode is just "noise") meaning you could safely use an 0603.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I know about power dissipation, but since on Bob Smith termination I don't expect to see any signals flowing, I wasn't sure if the power dissipation is relevant or not. Therefore, I want to know if anyone has a general idea about the package of this resistor. If the power dissipation could be calculated somehow, I would have understood properly which package to select.

Comment: @Andyaka Could you please tell what is "direct termination" in this context?

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie Thanks for your opinion. Actually the pins on which this termination is presented are unused, which makes it a little confusing to me.

Comment: Direct termination is the standard resistor(s) used to match the cable impedance between the wires of a twisted pair thus preventing (hopefully) reflections.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you mean series termination resistors on differential signals near the RJ45 connector, or some external resistors?

Comment: I have no mental picture of what you refer to. Some ethernet switch chips have internal terminations and some require external. I don't know your circuit so I can't answer that.

Comment: I am talking about the common Bob Smith termination used with Ethernet, that's why I did not post schematic. Sorry for that. The circuit is pretty typical: pins 1,2,3,6 of RJ45 connector are for TX and RX pairs. Unused pairs 4,5 and 7,8 as well as both the centre taps of transformer secondary are terminated using 75R for each connected to a 1nF capacitor to Earth/Shield. I want to reduce the size of these 75R resistors from 1206 to 0603 package if power dissipation is not a concern, hence thought to get some confirmation.

Comment: As there will be no signals on those resistors, in my opinion you can make them 0603, no problem.

Comment: Yeah right, thanks. I will change them to 0603. It will help the layout in achieving required clearance from nearby components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micrel uses 0603 on its demo boards, for example, see [KSZ8463ML/RL Eval Board](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/Ethernet/hw_designkit/KSZ8463/) documentation.

In mass dense products, such as mainboards, 0402 is normal way.

Comment: Thanks so much for the example. Gives more weight to the decision of going with 0603.