# Bob Smith Termination - Where should we use it?

Tags: voltage, current, signal, terminology, termination

What is a Bob-smith termination and why do we use it?

I've seen it being using in Ethernet RJ-45 connectors where it is terminated to Chassis ground?

Can someone tell me how this type of termination is useful and for what applications?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Bob Smith termination for Ethernet recommended if it's wrong?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161436/why-is-bob-smith-termination-for-ethernet-recommended-if-its-wrong)

Comment: dublicate of: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161436/why-is-bob-smith-termination-for-ethernet-recommended-if-its-wrong ?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to understand the question and the answer in that link. But I didn't receive any clarity. The link doesn't explicitly state the purpose of the applications of this termination. If someone can provide an answer, it will help me.

Comment: Please do a search of "Bob Smith" on this site, read what you find, and then let us know if they answer your question, and if not, why not.

Comment: is this an exam question?